# Interval of validity for initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^{4 }y^{ -5 }$, $y(0)=9$. For what x interval is the solution defined?

I thought the interval would be any real number, negative infinity to positive infinity, but that's incorrect. The upper interval is positive infinity, but I don't know what the lower bound is.

Comment: This is a [separable equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_(ODE)). Separate the variables, find the general solution, determine the integration constant from the initial value, and see on what interval the resulting function is defined.

Comment: $y^5dy=x^4dx$ then $y^6=\frac{6}{5}x^5+C$